# Is it possible to run TypeScript code in iOS JSContext or WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, typescript, wkwebview, jscontext

I'm looking for ways to include shared cross platform libraries in native iOS applications. My focus is on Javascript and Typescript sources.

I made a playground project which is loading a js file into JSContext (JavaScriptCore framework) and then I can call JavaSript functions from native Swift code:

```
let jsContext = JSContext()
let jsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "shared-lib", withExtension: "js")!
let jsScript = try String(contentsOf: jsURL, encoding: .utf8)
jsContext.evaluateScript(jsScript)

jsContext.setObject(
    param1,
    forKeyedSubscript: NSString(string: "param1")
)

jsContext.setObject(
    param2,
    forKeyedSubscript: NSString(string: "param2")
)

let resultJSValue = jsContext.evaluateScript("""
    calculate(param1, param2);
""")
```

I could also execute js code in WKWebView (WebKit framework), and get the result out of it.

But as soon as I'm trying to execute a simple function from a TypeScript file the result is `undefined` in both JSContext and WKWebView.

Is it possible at all to run TypeScript code in JSContext or WKWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript needs to be compiled into JavaScript. Browsers don't support TypeScript directly. So no, you cannot run TypeScript in a `JSContext` or `WKWebView` directly.